# ERROR: Project with path ':@react-native-firebase_app' could not be found in project ':@react-native-firebase_auth'

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

After install react-native-firebase and add module auth, showed this erro in Android Studio:

> ERROR: Project with path ':@react-native-firebase_app' could not be
>   found in project ':@react-native-firebase_auth'.

What does this mean?

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 6):

I have also faced the same issue.

After I install  `npm i @react-native-firebase/app` the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try the following:**

-Checking if firebase app was referenced in an incorrect way in MainApplication.java.

-Remove the modules and re-installing them may fix the problem sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have different versions of firebase/app and firebase/auth.
Just go in 'node module/@react-native-firebase' directory and check package json of both firebase/app and firebase/auth you will see different version.

This problem can also happen if you are using @react-native-firebase@6.2.0
if you check the build.gradle of firebase/auth in version 6.2.0

```
dependencies {
  api project(':@react-native-firebase_app')
  implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:${ReactNative.ext.getVersion("firebase", "bom")}")
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth"
}
```

So here is a problem that it is not able to find @firebase/app
and @firebase/auth depends on @firebase/app

And in @6.3.4 which is working fine for me have  build.gradle of @firebase/auth like below
so it is able to find @firebase/app

```
   if (findProject(':@react-native-firebase_app')) {
    api project(':@react-native-firebase_app')
  } else if (findProject(':react-native-firebase_app')) {
    api project(':react-native-firebase_app')
  } else {
    throw new GradleException('Could not find the react-native-firebase/app package, have you installed it?')
  }
  implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:${ReactNative.ext.getVersion("firebase", "bom")}")
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. run  `npm uni @react-native-firebase/auth`
2. then run this simple command `@react-native-firebase/auth@10.4.1`

I was using  `"@react-native-firebase/auth": "15.1.1",` and having the same problem , then i **downgrade** it to  `"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^10.4.1",` and it **worked**.

if you have any problem installing make sure to use **--legacy-peer-deps** at the end , like this:

`npm i @react-native-firebase/auth@10.4.1 --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: 10.8.1 should work better if you're using other firebase services like functions, storage and firestore